# Poweshell Exception "getsteppablepipeline" - Macos M2 chip

Tags: powershell, installation, module, macos-ventura

I installed powershell through homebrew and im getting the following exception whenever i try to install any module:

ParentContainsErrorRecordException: Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "0" argument(s): "The expression
after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must
result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object."

Expected modules to be installed to be able to connect to Microsoft admin center.

Comment: Welcome to SO, noob. Please copy and paste as text into the question the output of `$PSVersionTable`. Also, what are the names of the modules being installed.